# Polymer static variable listener?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have been trying to search without much luck. Say that you have a component `Racing Car`:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'racing-car',
  properties: {
     ready: { // this variable is intended to be static
       type: Boolean,
       value: false,
       observer: 'onCarReady'
     }
  },

  onCarReady: function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('time to run!');
  }
})
```

Elsewhere in your app, you initialize 4 racing car:

```
<racing-car id="car1"></racing-car>
<racing-car id="car2"></racing-car>
<racing-car id="car3"></racing-car>
<racing-car id="car4"></racing-car>
```

Not the best example of static variable, but I hope you get the idea.

Imagine a race, I'd like to change `ready` property of all racing car instances at once, but I'm not sure how to do so in Polymer. Of course I can do something like

```
<racing-car id="car1" ready="{{globalVariableReady}}"></racing-car>
<racing-car id="car2" ready="{{globalVariableReady}}"></racing-car>
<racing-car id="car3" ready="{{globalVariableReady}}"></racing-car>
<racing-car id="car4" ready="{{globalVariableReady}}"></racing-car>
```

but that feels kinda dumb.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
  properties: {
     ready: { // this variable is intended to be static
       type: Boolean,
       value: {{globalVariableReady}},
       observer: 'onCarReady'
     }
  },
```

Not in that fashion, but some way to globally change this property in all instances of `racing-car`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. `iron-meta` is what I'm looking for. Though it doesn't propagate with data binding so I used `akc-meta` instead, a similar version

Answer (score 0):

Polymer can't bind to a "global variable" if you are using that term that literally, i.e.

```
<script>var globalVariableReady = true;</script>
```

You could probably do what you want programmatically.  In some script that runs after the four racing-car elements have loaded, call:

```
document.querySelectorAll('racing-car').forEach(el => el.ready = true);
```

Note:  The code above assumes an ES6 compatible browser with [iterable node lists](https://medium.com/@devlucky/nodelist-object-is-finally-an-iterator-cc529d6e2490#.od8lb7kl7).

Using binding, though could make sense if the racing-car tags are inside a larger custom element you define, where you define a property called "globalVariableReady" to use your terminology.  Or inside an [autobind template](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-bind), where you set the value "globalVariableReady" once on the template element, which would then update all four child elements in rapid succession.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>

<body>
  <my-element></my-element>
  <my-element></my-element>
  <my-element></my-element>
  <my-element></my-element>
  <div onclick="changeValue()">click me to change value</div>
  <script>
    function changeValue() {
      glob = "new Value";

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>




<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    click me to check the value
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  var glob = 'initial Value';
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    listeners: {
      'tap': '_onTap'
    },
    _onTap: function() {
      alert(glob);
    }
  });
</script>
```